# How to auto resize uploaded image using php

Tags: php, file-upload, autoresize

I have a script;

```
        $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

        // get the file extension first
        $ext = substr(strrchr($fileName, "."), 1); 

        // make the random file name
        $randName = md5(rand() * time());

        // and now we have the unique file name for the upload file
        $filePath = $imagesDir . $randName . '.' . $ext;

        $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);
        if (!$result) {
            echo "Error uploading file";
        exit;
    } 

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
        $filePath = addslashes($filePath);

    }
```

which am using to upload images but I would like to add a script to resize the image to a specific size before it's uploaded. How do I do that???

Comment: This would do it for you easily .... http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I would make sure the file name is unique though, the chance is ridiculously low but not impossible

Comment: @Baba thanx for that but it's too complicated! lol! Isn't there a simpler method???

Comment: @gosukiwi are you referring to my script or Baba's?

Comment: yours, md5 can path several strings to the same hash, i know the chance is ridiculously low but i don't know, considering those little things is what makes a program more robust

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: I have updated this to include your script elements. I'm starting from the point where you obtain your filename.

Here is a very quick, simple script to do it:

```
$result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);
$orig_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filePath);
$image_info = getimagesize($filePath); 
$width_orig  = $image_info[0]; // current width as found in image file
$height_orig = $image_info[1]; // current height as found in image file
$width = 1024; // new image width
$height = 768; // new image height
$destination_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopyresampled($destination_image, $orig_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
// This will just copy the new image over the original at the same filePath.
imagejpeg($destination_image, $filePath, 100);
```

Comment: looks good @davidethell but how do I fuse that with my script above??? Would be great if that can be achieved!

Comment: @JaySmoke, I have updated this example to include your $filePath variable.

Comment: great but there's an error with the script. where is $img_source getting it's data from???

Comment: when I upload, i get the error "getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the example. I had missed that one.

Comment: *sidenote:* you probably want `imagedestroy($destination_image);` after the last line to free memory.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor, that's a good point, but only necessary if you have more script execution after the image manipulation. PHP destroys the image when the script stops anyway so imagedestroy is important when processing more than one image or with a large script that has more logic after the image manipulation.

Comment: agree. but a server should serve multiple users concurrently. leaving more memory ASAP to others is always better

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't change the size of it before it's uploaded, but you can use the GD Library to change the size of it after it's on the server. Check out [GD and Image Functions listing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php)  for all of the related functions for dealing with images.

There is also [this tutorial](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/) that will show you a custom class for doing a resize, but unless you need the whole think you can focus on the function resize to see how it's done